# How to properly delete pointers when using abstract classes

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following classes and objects:

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal
{
public:
    virtual void makeNoise() = 0;

    void eat()
    {
        std::cout << "Eating..." << "\n";
    }

    void sleep()
    {
        std::cout << "Sleeping..." << "\n";
    }
};

class Cat: public Animal
{
public:
    void makeNoise()
    {
        std::cout << "Miow..." << "\n";
    }
};

class Cow: public Animal
{
public:
    void makeNoise()
    {
        std::cout << "Mooo..." << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Animal *animal;
    Cat *cat = new Cat();
    Cow *cow = new Cow();

    animal = cat;
    animal->eat();
    animal->sleep();
    animal->makeNoise();

    animal = cow;
    animal->eat();
    animal->sleep();
    animal->makeNoise();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that animal is an abstract class.

How can I properly delete the pointers `animal`, `cat` and `cow`?

When I try to `delete animal;` I get the following warning message:

> warning: deleting object of abstract class type 'Animal' which has
>   non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behaviour.

In the other hand, when I try to `delete cat;` I get the following message:

> warning: deleting object of polymorphic class type 'Cat' which has
>   non-virtual destructor might cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: Do as the warning says and make the `Animal` destructor `virtual`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A basic C++ rule says that destructors work their way up from the derived class to the base class. When a `Cat` is destroyed, then the `Cat` part is destroyed first and the `Animal` part is destroyed after.

`delete animal;` is undefined behaviour because in order to properly follow C++ destruction rules, one must know, at runtime, which derived class part should be destroyed before the `Animal` base part. A `virtual` destructor does exactly that - it enables a dynamic dispatch mechanism that makes sure destruction works as designed.

You have no `virtual` destructor, however, so `delete animal` just doesn't make sense. There is no way to call the correct derived-class destructor, and destroying only the `Animal` part wouldn't exactly be meaningful behaviour, either.

Therefore, the C++ language makes no assumptions about what will happen in such a situation.

Your compiler is nice enough to warn you about this.

---

With `delete cat`, the situation is slightly different. The static type of the `cat` pointer is `Cat*`, not `Animal*`, so it is clear even without any dynamic dispatch mechanism which derived-class destructor to call first.

The compiler still warns you about this, but it does so with a different wording ("might cause" vs. "will cause"). I believe the reason is that `Cat` might itself be the base class for more derived classes, seeing as it is already part of a class hierarchy with `virtual` functions.

It apparently doesn't bother to execute a more complete code analysis to find out that `delete cat` is really harmless.

---

In order to fix this, make the `Animal` destructor `virtual`. While you're at it, replace your raw pointers with `std::unique_ptr`. You still have to follow the `virtual` destructor rule for classes like yours, but you no longer have to perform a manual `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what the compiler is warning you about.  You need to define and implement your own destructors for each class, and make sure they are defined as `virtual` for inheritance.